# How can I combine multiple textarea sets within PHP to output to a file?

Tags: php, html, string, textarea

Currently I have a form with 3 text areas.

[It looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfvPf.png)

There is a button which sends the data to the PHP backend and creates a word document of this data and then downloads it for the user. This is a multi-line textarea obviously so the issue I am running into is that I am having trouble getting the proper formatting within this word document.

So for example if my textarea is setup like so:

```
Textbox1                     Textbox2                Textbox3
File1                        N/A                     600
File2                        Use Tab 1               1000
File3                        Use Tab 2               200
```

I would expect the output in the word document to be just

```
File1                        N/A                     600
File2                        Use Tab 1               1000
File3                        Use Tab 2               200
```

But what I get is

```
 File1
File2
File3       N/A
Use Tab 1
Use Tab 2       600
1000
200
```

In exactly this format. HOWEVER, if I only had one line (say the File1 line) it would actually output how I want it to. How can I setup my PHP string to format to my desired output?
My PHP is

```
if (strlen($multipleImports) > 0) {
    $content = $content . "\n\n" . "Imports:\n ";
    $content = $content . $multipleImports  . $multipleImportsInfo  . $multipleImportsCounts;
}
```

Comment: use an array to add object with all the needed information inside and just use for loop to get the multiple values you're looking for.

Comment: Oh that was really easy... I will answer my own question then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
$multipleImports = explode("\n",$multipleImports);
$multipleImportsInfo = explode("\n",$multipleImportsInfo);
$multipleImportsCounts = explode("\n",$multipleImportsCounts);
$content = $content . "\n\n" . "Imports:\n ";

$length = count($multipleImports);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $content = $content . $multipleImports[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsInfo[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsCounts[$i] . "\n ";
}
```